# Unrooted test error while using "Background" in Cucumber feature file

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am new to Selenium and practicing Cucumber. I am doing a sample project in which I created a "CreateLead" test. The test executes successfully using Junit when I do not use "Background:" in the feature file.

If I include the "Background:" in the feature file, I  face "unrooted test" exception. Can someone please help me to resolve this?

**CreateLead Feature File**

```
Feature: Creating Lead

In order to get more revenue 
As a sales person 
I want to create leads

Background:
Given I am logged in salesforce in Mozilla
Given I am logged in salesforce in Chrome

@CreateLead
Scenario Outline: Creating Leads
Given Browser is "<Browser>"
And I click on the tab "LeadTab"
And I click on the button "NewLeadButton"

Examples:
  |Browser  |
  |Mozilla  |
  |Chrome   |
```

**CreateLeadTest**

```
package com.qtpselenium.CreateLeadTestCase;

import org.junit.Assert;

import com.qtpselenium.util.Webconnector;

import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class CreateLeadTest {
    Webconnector Selenium= Webconnector.getInstance();

    @Given("^I am logged in salesforce in \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_am_logged_in_salesforce(String browser) throws Throwable{
    Selenium.openBrowser(browser);
    Assert.assertTrue("Not logged in", Selenium.isLoggedIn());
    }

    @Given("^Browser is \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void Browser_is(String browser) throws Throwable{
        Selenium.openBrowser(browser);
        Selenium.isLoggedIn();
    }

    @And("^I click on the tab \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_click_on_the_tab(String object)throws Throwable{
        Selenium.click(object);
    }

    @And("^I click on the button \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_click_on_the_button(String object)throws Throwable{
        Selenium.click(object);
    }
```

**Error:**
Unrooted tests-
@Ignore:Given I am logged in Salesforce in Mozilla
@Ignore:Given I am logged in Salesforce in Chrome

Comment: Please include your JUnit test runner code.  That is, the code containing statement @RunWith(Cucumber.class). BTW, make sure that you are running with junit 4 as running with junit 3 has been known to cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Background** start to run before the ***Scenario*** and end with ***Hooks***.

Try to delete the "Given I am logged in salesforce in Chrome" from the background and execute the test. Which means that we aim to run the test in Mozilla for this instance.

I am sure the test executes succesfully